# How to prevent jquery mobile app for iphone to auto stretch in ipad

Tags: ios, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have an app designed for iphone in jquery mobile and phonegap. It works fine on iphone or ipod. but the moment i open it on ipad, it stretches it self in the ipad for fluid layout i guess. So how do i prevent it so that it will be centered like other apps.**strong text**!

[this is the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvc8k.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly believe this problem is due to your CSS and how you are sizing your elements. It hard to know for sure without seeing some code, but my guess would be that you are sizing your elements using percentages (i.e. `.button{width:30%;}`) so elements get sized relative to the outter container, which seems to be the size of the screen of the device you are using. If this is the case,

One option would be to change all percentage sizes of inner elements from percentages to pixels. Another option would be to wrap all child elements in using one parent div and set the size of that parent div to some static size using pixels, which will allow you keep all percentage values of child elements the same.